# How to deal with the memory leak in iphone application

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

Today I faced a problem that there is one memory leak in my iphone application.

below is the screenshot.

when I double click the leak block,

the memory leak detection instrument gives me some assembly code not source code

so I could not find out where the memory leaks,I confused me a lot,and last night I didn't

sleep well.

Could someBody give me some advice to deal with such things?

Thank you!!!

[image: iphone memory leak]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this leak is being caused by a closed source library, so you wouldn't be able to directly change the code.

You should make sure that you are properly using the framework methods, as sometimes your actions can indirectly trigger leaks with private API's and Instruments is pretty bad at catching and properly reporting that kind of thing.

A good place to start might be Build and Analyze.